# Uipath Error:Compilation failed or was cancelled

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

[image]

I was trying to debug the xaml file, but it shows the Error message saying compilation failed or was cancelled. I can't find any error while developing the process. The activities I used are also falling under the same error while testing them.

Comment: In order to get help you need to deliver more infos. Which version of Studio. Show the xaml code and so on.